# Append the time stamp to a file name in Ubuntu

Tags: linux, bash, timestamp

I have a bash script that I use to backup the contents of a SSD every day however I use the following command in the script to name the file

```
zip -r ssd-$(date "+%b_%d_%Y").zip ../ssd
```

It already appends the month, day, and year to the file name however how can I modify that to also append the timestamp of the server onto the file name as well?

Answer (score 20):

Add `_%H_%M_%S` into the date-format string as well.  For example, `date +%b_%d_%Y_%H_%M_%S` produces a string like
`Oct_07_2012_17_57_36`.  For a shorter string, consider format %s; eg, `date +%s` produces a string like 1349654346, the number of seconds since 1970-01-01 00:00:00 UTC.

Answer (score 4):

Does the following do what you need?

```
date "+%b_%d_%Y_%H.%M.%S"
```